# Google Chromecast: MediaLoad error when casting hls streams

Tags: chromecast

I am using default media player app to cast hls streams containing play list **.m3u8** and **.ts** files using Cast extension enabled chromebrowser from PC. After the first .ts chunk is fetched by the Chromecast receiver app (default reciver app) the second chunk transfer is cancelled with error:

```
media_player.js:24 Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.     

media_player.js:104 ######### MEDIA ELEMENT ERROR [object Event] 
mpl.js:153 [274.530s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error 
cast_receiver.js:18 
### Media Manager - LOAD METADATA ERROR: {"senderId":"6:client-4751","message":{"requestId":82952020,"sessionId":"0EAD5DA1-2932-1687-B2EA-0C84D1DFD165","media": "contentId":"server_ip/hls_rec/master.m3u8","streamType":"BUFFERED","contentType":"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0,"customData":{"payload":{"title":"Gravlab HLS"}}}}
```

Full log below:

```
[273.342s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"IDLE\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"idleReason\":\"INTERRUPTED\"}],\"requestId\":0}"} cast_receiver.js:18

### Media Manager - LOAD: {"type":"load","H":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"cb":true,"data":{"requestId":82952020,"sessionId":"0EAD5DA1-2932-1687-B2EA-0C84D1DFD165","media":{"contentId":"server_ip/hls_rec/master.m3u8","streamType":"BUFFERED","contentType":"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0,"customData":{"payload":{"title":"Gravlab HLS"}}},"senderId":"6:client-4751"} mpl.js:559
 [273.096s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload 
 media_player.js:24
### Media Protocol Identified as HLS mpl.js:642
 [273.123s] [cast.player.api.Player] Version: 0.7.0.5
 media_player.js:24
 [273.129s] [cast.player.api.Player] load 
 media_player.js:24
######### MEDIA ELEMENT LOAD START mpl.js:57
 [273.262s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET server_ip/hls_rec/master.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.277s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET server_ip/hls_rec/master.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.282s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET server_ip/hls_rec/master.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.329s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET server_ip/hls_rec/master.m3u8 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.370s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: from undefined to 2265024
 media_player.js:24
 [273.376s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: server_ip/hls_rec/01.m3u8
 media_player.js:24
 [273.381s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET server_ip/hls_rec/01.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.386s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET server_ip/hls_rec/01.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.391s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET server_ip/hls_rec/01.m3u8 -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.511s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET server_ip/hls_rec/01.m3u8 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.567s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: seek success 0
 media_player.js:24
 [273.574s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET server_ip/hls_rec/1.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.580s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 10000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET server_ip/hls_rec/1.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [273.585s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET server_ip/hls_rec/1.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [274.142s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET server_ip/hls_rec/1.ts 200]
 media_player.js:24
 [274.151s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: current=7802648.28, average=6090999.39
 media_player.js:24
 [274.171s] [cast.player.hls.Protocol] start: 3.2835444444444444
 media_player.js:24
 [274.177s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: abort
 media_player.js:24
 [274.182s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: timestampOffset = -3.2835444444444444
 media_player.js:24
 [274.187s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:24
 [274.205s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET server_ip/hls_rec/2.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [274.209s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 10000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET server_ip/hls_rec/2.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
 [274.212s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET server_ip/hls_rec/2.ts -1]
 media_player.js:24
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. media_player.js:104
######### MEDIA ELEMENT ERROR [object Event] mpl.js:153
 [274.530s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error cast_receiver.js:18
### Media Manager - LOAD METADATA ERROR: {"senderId":"6:client-4751","message":{"requestId":82952020,"sessionId":"0EAD5DA1-2932-1687-B2EA-0C84D1DFD165","media":{"contentId":"server_ip/hls_rec/master.m3u8","streamType":"BUFFERED","contentType":"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0,"customData":{"payload":{"title":"Gravlab HLS"}}}} mpl.js:411
 [274.541s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Resetting media element cast_receiver.js:18
 [274.552s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 6:client-4751 cast_receiver.js:18
 [274.560s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"6:client-4751","data":"{\"requestId\":82952020,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [274.319s] [cast.player.api.Player] error
 media_player.js:24 ### HOST ERROR - Fatal Error: code = 1 mpl.js:622
 [274.331s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload
```

Any idea what this error means? The stream format of video and audio streams are H.264 video and AAC Audio which are supported by the chromecast media player.Content Streamed is from IIS Server with CORS enabled.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is something in the stream that the player is not happy about, to further debug this, you need to open a ticket on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list) and include your stream so we can debug that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I opened a ticket in issue tracker and uploaded streams. Issue 372: Uncaught InvalidStateError: in media_player.js when casting hls streams